# Read a shapefile with character encoding

Tags: r, shapefile, r-maptools

Is there a way to read a shape file with a specific character encoding? I'm trying to read in a Canadian shapefile that has special (French) characters in some of the names. I can convert them manually, but I'd prefer not to do this if there's a setting somewhere that I'm so far blind to.

```
# manual conversion works
library(maptools)
shp <- file.path("path/to/file.shp")
map <- readShapePoly(shp, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:25832"))
map$ERNAME <- iconv(map$ERNAME, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: What about `readOGR()` in the rgdal package? There are two arguments, which you may be able to use: encoding and use_iconv.

Comment: I'm going to try that out and get back to you!

Comment: @jazzurro please post as answer. It worked for me.

Comment: The syntax with `rgdal` is: `pasl=readOGR(".","filename", use_iconv=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: @user3386170 please consider adding your comment as an answer!

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Done!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using, `maptools` and the `readShapePoly` arguments, using the `rgdal` library with `readOGR` function allows for more options. For example, the syntax with rgdal could be:

```
pasl=readOGR(".","filename", use_iconv=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Be aware that this is not a universal solution but depends on the encoding of the file, which in the OP case was `UTF-8`. Common encoding also includes `latin1`. In some shapefiles, the encoding is named in the `.cpg` file (open with a text editor software) along with the `.shp` file. `QGIS` automatically generates a `.cpg` file when a new shapefile is created but many other GIS software do not.